# How to find nontrivial solution for $\Psi$ in the given matrix equation?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the matrix equation $\mathbf M\mathbf \Psi=\mathbf 0$ where $\mathbf M$ and $\mathbf \Psi $ are given below. I check that that $\det \mathbf M=\mathbf 0$; that is,

```
Det [M] // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> δ ∈ Reals && σ ∈ Reals] & 
(*0*)
```

so, since the problem comes from a physics eigenvalue problem, there MUST be a nontrivial solution for $\mathbf \Psi$; but when I use the `Solve` code, it gives only a trivial solution

```
Solve[M  Ψ == 0, Ψ] 
(*{{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0, 
   e -> 0, f -> 0, g -> 0, h -> 0, i -> 0, j -> 0, k -> 0, l -> 0, 
   m -> 0, n -> 0, o -> 0, p -> 0, q -> 0, r -> 0, s -> 0, t -> 0}}*)
```

**Question**.

> More important, since $\mathbf \Psi$ is an eigenfunction and I want to normalize it, I want to obtain variables in $\mathbf \Psi$ in terms of one of them, here, I remove the variable $a$ but the `Solve` code gives nothing

```
Solve[M  Ψ == 0, { b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, 
   q, r, s, t}] 
(*{}*)
```

Here are the codes for matrix $\mathbf M$ and eigenfunction $\mathbf \Psi$:

```
 M = {{0, -2, 0, 2 E^((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    2 E^((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 2, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 2 E^(I ((4 π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]) + σ )), 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {-2 E^(-((4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])) + I σ ), 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 
    0, 0, 0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 
    2 E^((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) \[Pi])/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 
    2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 
    0, 0, 0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])))}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2 E^(I (δ + (4 π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, -2 E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     0, -2 E^(I δ - (4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 2 E^((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(-((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 0, 0, 
    2 E^(I ((4 π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]) + σ )), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 E^(I (δ + (4 π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2 E^(-((4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])) + I σ ), 
    0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2 E^(I δ - (4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 
    2 E^((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}};

Ψ = { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, 
   t};
```

Comment: I think there's a tricky part: you said it yourself, there **MIGHT** be a non-trivial solution for $\Psi$. There might as well not be. Do you have reasons to believe that it exists?

Comment: Also, is it possible that you wanted to write `Solve[M . Ψ == 0, {b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t}]`?

Comment: @bmf Yes, by reasons that I am not going to share here, I am sure there MUST be a nontrivial solution. The problem comes form a physics eigenvalue problem.

Comment: You should have provided this piece of information in the OP, so people know. Also, can you please comment on the second question I asked? Do you want `a b` or `a.b` with `a` and `b` some matrices?

Comment: @bmf I am not familiar with matrix equations and matrix products in Mathematica, but $M$ and $\Psi$ are both matrices with dimensions $(20,20)$ and $(20,1)$ respectively.

Comment: Unless I have utterly misunderstood your question, isn't this just `NullSpace[M]`? The result of that squares with the fact that `MatrixRank[M]` gives 16, so solutions like in Bob's answer could be built as a linear combination of the null vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol = Assuming[{δ, σ} ∈ Reals,
  Solve[Thread[M . ψ == 0], ψ][[1]] // Simplify]

(* Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

{a -> E^(-((4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))) r, 
 d -> b E^(-((2 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
 e -> b E^(-((4 I (-1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
 g -> c E^(-((2 I (6 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
 h -> E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))) f, 
 i -> E^(-((4 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))) f, 
 j -> b E^(I ((4 π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]) + σ)), 
 k -> c E^(-((2 I (4 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
 l -> E^(-((10 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])) + I σ) r, 
 m -> E^(I δ) f, 
 n -> E^(I ((2 (1 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]) + σ)) r, 
 o -> E^(-((2 I (3 + 2 Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])) + I δ) f,
  p -> c E^(-((2 I (2 + Sqrt[3]) π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))), 
 q -> b E^(-((4 I Sqrt[3] π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])) + I δ), 
 s -> E^(-((2 I π)/(3 + Sqrt[3]))) r, 
 t -> c E^(-((2 I Sqrt[3] π)/(3 + Sqrt[3])))} *)

Length@sol

(* 16 *)
```

Checking solution,

```
And @@ Thread[M . ψ == 0] /. sol // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** To normalize ψ

```
(ψN = Assuming[{δ, σ} ∈ Reals,
    Normalize[ψ /. sol] // Simplify]) // Short[#, 10] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote in the text, I want to normalize the eigenfunction $\Psi$, so, I want to have all the $20$ elements of $\{a,b,c,...,t\}$ in terms of only one of them, say $a$?  Now, you have obtained $16$ of these elements in terms of the other four $r,f,b,c$; does this mean that one cannot normalize $\Psi$?

Answer (score 3):

I gave you a hint and I am sure you did not check. Otherwise, the response would not have been `I am not familiar with matrix equations and matrix products in Mathematica`

Take a simple minimal working example.

Consider two matrices, that are small with arbitrary elements. Write once `a b` and another time `a.b` and do `MatrixForm` to see the difference of the output.

You should have inspected this

[image: screen]

Now, it is **CLEAR** that one is the ordinary matrix multiplication while the other is something else.

Which one do you want? That was the question, which has nothing to do with the software. It has to do with what you want to consider.

So, my question was are you sure you wanted to write `M Ψ`? Or perhaps you wanted to write `M.Ψ`?

If the latter, here's the solution in a split second

[image: sltn]

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I meant the latter option in your answer, i.e. $M.\Psi$. As I wrote in the text, I want to normalize the eigenfunction $\Psi$, so, I want to have all the $20$ elements of $\{a,b,c,...,t\}$ in terms of only one of them, say $a$?  Now, you have obtained $16$ of these elements in terms of the other four $a,f,b,c$; does this mean that one cannot normalize $\Psi$?